# How to change background image randomly every load

Tags: html, css

How can I change the background image randomly from several sub folderseverytime the page is reloaded?

Imagine that the background file name is wallpaper.jpg
And in the folder images, I have subfolders and inside everyone of them I have one picture with the same name 'wallpaper.jpg'.
My goal is everytime we reload the page, the wallpaper changes randomly selecting one wallpaper.jpg from all the subfolders from the. Images folder.

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: https://ma.tt/scripts/randomimage/ There is a tutorial and live demo here on how you can do this.

Comment: Do you know the subfolder names in advance? Or are they predictable (subfolder-1, subfolder-2, etc)?

Comment: The subfolders will have different names

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to make a naming pattern for the folders. Or put all the images in one folder with a naming pattern. I assume that your folder  names are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
let folderCount= 5;
function refresh() 
{
let rand= Math.ceil( Math.random() * folderCount);
document.body.background = images/'+num+'/wallpaper.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But we must presume that the subfolders names could be anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with JavaScript like this:

```
let element = document.querySelector("body");
let arrImages = ["pathForImage1", "pathForImage2", "pathForImage3"];
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrImages.length);  


element.style.background = "url(" + arrImages[randomNumber] + ")";
```

Comment: But this will not work if we don't know the exact name of the subfolders... And we do not, it could be anything